# Re-sizing to 1024px produces horizontal scroll bar...but all divs measure 1024px

Tags: html, css

I need some help:

http://www.stansellelectric.com

If you go to any page on this website and re-size your monitor (or Firefox browser if you use the Web Developer toolbar) down to 1024x768, a horizontal scrollbar will appear both in the #contentwrap div and the page itself. Now, increasing the width of the window to 1039px fixes this, however I need it to stay at 1024px and not have a scrollbar anywhere.

I'm stuck, help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1024 pixels is the total width of the screen.

In order to fit content on a 1024 pixel screen, you need to account for the *vertical* scroll bar (usually 16-24px in width) and (in some browsers) the window's edge. These will take away horizontal space.

Bottom line: You need to use a smaller width for your content than 1024 pixels. A number that is popular among designers is 960 pixels, also because that can be evenly divided; it's used e.g. by the [960 grid system](http://960.gs/), a popular CSS framework.

However, in my experience, a slightly higher number (like 980 or even 1000) will also work well for the majority of devices.

Comment: Before I attempt to question that, I need a little more information about what you mean. Sorry, I was a little confused at what you said

Comment: @TTU I edited it a bit to make it clearer, does that work for you?

Comment: This is a good answer. More of a design constraint, or something to be aware of.

Comment: Yes, makes perfect sense now. I removed the vertical scroll bar dynamically with Firebug and the horizontal one went away as well. Now I have to restructure the code a bit, lol. Much appreciated!

Comment: As stated make sure you always undercut the number of pixels you are designing for. There are even some monitors that do funky things where even though the resolution is 1024 they cut part off. When designing for a width of 1024 its my experience that 1000px is the highest you should go. That usually takes care of the vertical scroll and most weird stuff monitors do.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Pekka's answer fixed it for me. Previous coder for this website built the site to 1024px entirely. We've been building them at 960 since I started. Fixed the site down to 1000px and it's working great. Much appreciated!!!